# How to know which apps requested Fused Location API

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using Fused Location API in my project to get the Location.

But the problem is my app doesn't appear in the Android Setting -> Location -> Recent Location Request's Section.

I was trying to know why this is happening?

After searching for a while, I remembered that the Fused Location Services was part of Google Play Services, and when I went to see the same in the Above path, I saw the "Google Play services(Battery usage: low)" and "Google App(Battery usage:low)".

Is Google Play Services appearing as a proxy for my app for requesting the Location and how to know which App actually requested the Location through Fused Location API?

Comment: are you requesting location permission  in manifest file

Comment: Yes, I used everything as described in the [documentation] (http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Comment: I am under the impression that Google should show which apps have actually requested Fused Location API Services, but when I checked the Location Settings for Google Play services I couldn't find this information.